# dplyr::summarise works for n() but not for sd() or mean() - "argument "x" is missing, with no default"

Tags: r, dplyr

Colleagues,
I want to summarise a data set, grouped by factors.
**dplyr::summarise** is happpy to give me sample sizes with **n()**, but gives an error, **argument "x" is missing with no default** when I ask for something else, such as **mean()**.
Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

```r
library(dplyr)

#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

# create a dataset

data <- data.frame(
  name = c(rep("A", 500), rep("B", 500), rep("C", 20), rep("D", 100)),
  value = c(rnorm(500, 10, 5), rnorm(500, 13, 1), rnorm(20, 25, 4), rnorm(100, 12, 1))
)

# sample size

sample_size <- data |>
  group_by(name) |>
  summarize(num = n())

# sample means

sample_mean <- data |>
group_by(name) |>
summarise(mu = mean())

#> Error: Problem with `summarise()` column `mu`.
#> i `mu = mean()`.
#> x argument "x" is missing, with no default
#> i The error occurred in group 1: name = "A".
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: As you are loading the `dplyr`, can use `%>%` instead of `|>`.  The summarise step would be `summarize(num = mean(value))` `n()` is a special function which doesn't need any argument, while `mean` and other functions need the column name as unquoted

Comment: First, use `%>%` instead of `|%`. Second, `summarise(mu = mean(value))`.

Comment: Thank you _akrun_ and _zhiqiang-wang_ for your very quick replys. I knew it would be something embarrassingly simple.